# Ubuntu can't download files during update to 12.04 (Failed to fetch)

Tags: 11.10, networking, upgrade, downloads

I have a fail during upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 (Failed to fetch)

I've been trying to update ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04 for a while (from Update manager). But every time I do the update, after updater finished (as it shoes on progress bar) downloading of more then 2000 files, manager halts for 5 minuts and then show me following:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-nanum/fonts-nanum_3.010-2_all.deb Соединение разорвано [IP: 91.189.88.25 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-unfonts-core/fonts-unfonts-core_1.0.3.is.1.0.2-080608-5ubuntu1_all.deb Соединение разорвано [IP: 91.189.88.28 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/ttf-wqy-microhei/ttf-wqy-microhei_0.2.0-beta-1ubuntu1_all.deb Соединение разорвано [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
```

"Соединение разорвано" -- translates as "Connection is broken"

I've also switched to Russian Server. The same issue.

```
Failed to fetch http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-nanum/fonts-nanum_3.010-2_all.deb Соединение разорвано
Failed to fetch http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-unfonts-core/fonts-unfonts-core_1.0.3.is.1.0.2-080608-5ubuntu1_all.deb Соединение разорвано
Failed to fetch http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/ttf-wqy-microhei/ttf-wqy-microhei_0.2.0-beta-1ubuntu1_all.deb Соединение разорвано
```

I try it for more then 2 weeks and every time happens all the same. Some times Ubuntu pops-up me "Whould you like to update" notification with "Update" button. Some times I do it manualy from update manager.

But also I **can't** manualy download following files -- browser (chromium) stops on half way of downloading them, wget halts at some piont.

Downloading problems are only on my machine in our office. My college on MAC have no problems to get this files manualy.

I've never played with iptables or anything else on my machine.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible that there is another firewall that is affecting this? Another route would be to upgrade from the 12.04 iso, avoiding the fetch issue...

Comment: @Mordoc I have never installed any software that have firewall functionality. But I'll walk through installed software again to find out anything about it. For me it looks strange, when downloading breaks every time I request file. And every time on the same stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was out of my PC. Today I've decided to switch to another ethernet socket, and magic happened: all broken URLs suddenly fixed (why did not I do this later...). Seems to be the problem in switch. Question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading the ISO installation image for Ubuntu 12.04 and then burning it to a CD or USB. Booting off that, just choose the upgrade option and it should upgrade your system in place, which would bypass the need to download those packages (since they're inside the ISO).

Sorry but I can't really help on why you're getting those Connection Broken messages. If all other download traffic works, then I would look and see if your office is using some tricky proxy or firewall that might cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm already downloading alternate iso for this purpose. I've already found this answer, but still it's very suspicious behaviour. And i think it is my ubuntu issue, not the network. I'll talk to one who manage our office router, but I don`t think that he hates me so much ;)